# change DATEDIFF function result according to time in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query like this:

```
 SELECT t.Compl
    ,t.dtime
    ,case when l.edt is null or l.edt =0 then l.minEdt +l.BuffrEDT 
          else l.edt + l.BuffrEDT 
     end as EDT
    ,t.locid
    ,t.vtid
    ,t.lsttic
    ,c.Colname
    ,te.UniqueName
    ,DATEDIFF(minute,t.dtime,getdate()) as Duration, 
  FROM dbo.Transaction_tbl t
  left join PlateSource_tbl pl 
       on t.PSID=pl.PSID
  left join PlateCode_tbl pc 
       on t.PCdID=pc.PCdID
  left JOIN Color_tbl C 
       ON t.colid = c.colid 
  left JOIN Terminals_tbl te 
       ON k.tid = te.tid
  WHERE t.tbarcode = @carid
```

now i am getting duration in minutes..i want to get if the time is more that 60 minutes it need to show 1hr: 20 minutes other wise (if the time is less than 60 minutes then need to show only minutes)..how i can do that?

I try to give code duration like this:

```
convert(varchar(12),
        DATEDIFF(minute,Datediff(minute,t.dtime,getdate()),0),114
       ) as Duration
```

but that time getting result like this:-253440
actullay Duration is getting in minutes :178

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write as:

```
CONVERT(varchar(5), DATEADD(mi, Datediff(minute,t.dtime,getdate()) , 0), 114)
```

Hope this helps!!

[EDIT]

```
Case when Datediff(minute,t.dtime,getdate()) < 60 
then Cast (Datediff(minute,t.dtime,getdate()) as varchar)
else  CONVERT(varchar(5), DATEADD(mi, Datediff(minute,t.dtime,getdate()) , 0), 114)
end as Duration
```

Comment: mam now i am getting result like this:03:15:00:000 i need only 03:15

Comment: ok,,thanks..but if i get differnce in only minutes i dont want to show the hour column,,if the minutes is more than 60 then only i want to show hour column..

Comment: But that's not a good practice you should have a commom format for all the values in a given column .. say as HH:MM

Comment: Mam.but my customer need out put like that..i try to write using case statement..but it s showing some error?

Comment: Check edit.. yes error with case statement will occur if you won't add cast in first case..as output of both the cases should be varchar()

Answer (score 0):

For example 200 min into 3hrs 20min

select minutevalue/60 AS hrs,minutevalue%60 AS Minutes FROM Table

Here insteat of MinuteValue, your DATEDIFF function will go DATEDIFF(minute,t.dtime,getdate()) .

Comment: so i have to use case statemnt here?

Comment: Yes yes. Use case statement, when minutes > 60 go for this logic.
May i know your destination column datatype.